# Symplectic Runge-Kutta methods

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

We can solve some differential equation numerically using [Runge-Kutta methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods). i.e. for some function $f(x,y) = \frac{dy}{dx}$, then

$$ y_{n+1} = y_n + \sum_{i=1}^{s} c_i k_i $$

where e.g.

$$ k_2 = f(x_n+a_2 h, y_n + b_{21}k_1)$$

and $a_i$, $b_{ij}$ are some coefficeints e.g. [Cash-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cash%E2%80%93Karp_method).

---

Now, I understand that there also exist [symplectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator) Runge-Kutta methods. How would this method work? What would be the equivalent $y_{n+1}$ style equations for a symplectic Runge-Kutta? How are the coefficients chosen?

Comment: This isn't an answer, however, some links that may be helpful include --  [excellent Q&A on scicomp SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29149/what-does-symplectic-mean-in-reference-to-numerical-integrators-and-does-scip), [lecture notes by Ernst Hairer](http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/poly_geoint/week2.pdf), [article in *J. Comput. Math.* by Geng Sun](http://www.global-sci.org/jcm/volumes/v18n1/pdf/181-61.pdf).

Comment: Using a symplectic method only makes sense if you have something Hamiltonian-looking (i.e. dividing your states into two).

Answer (score 1):

The following is sufficient and necessary for a Runge-Kutta method to be symplectic:
$$
b_i a_{i,j} + b_j a_{j,i} - b_ib_j = 0 \, \quad 1 \leq i,j \leq s
$$
where $s$ is the number of stages in your method. No explicit RK methods achieve this.

This condition is in addition to other consistency conditions too.

Also, don't forget the $dt$ in your method, and the convention is to use $b_i$ in the linear combination of stage derivatives $k_i$, $c_i$ multiplied by $h=dt$, and $a_{i,j}$ for the states.

source: http://www.sanzserna.org/pdf/56_physicaD.pdf

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this applies to symplectic Runge-Kutta methods, but generally methods may be symplectic but not Runge-Kutta.

Comment: This applies to the use of standard RK methods, like the midpoint method. A larger number of symplectic methods are constructed as partitioned methods, with different, but coupled stages for the position and impulse components of the system.

Comment: Indeed. But those methods are not Runge-Kutta per se, so I am answering the OP.